How to set an empty environment variable
I need to set an empty environment variable in GitHub Actions, specifically RUSTFLAGS="" in order to prevent cargo from reading rustflags from .cargo/config.toml.
However, the following does not work:
run: echo "RUSTFLAGS=" >> $GITHUB_ENV

The var is not set:
  env:
    CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
    CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
    CARGO_PROFILE_DEV_STRIP: debuginfo
    CARGO_PROFILE_TEST_STRIP: debuginfo
    CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_STRIP: debuginfo

The following also doesn't work, as it sets the var to be two single quotes, literally:
run: echo "RUSTFLAGS=''" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  env:
    CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
    CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
    CARGO_PROFILE_DEV_STRIP: debuginfo
    CARGO_PROFILE_TEST_STRIP: debuginfo
    CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_STRIP: debuginfo
    RUSTFLAGS: ''

How can I set an env var to empty string in GitHub Actions?

For the AB problem I will set "RUSTFLAGS=--cfg noop" for now

Try setting double quotes: run: echo 'RUSTFLAGS=""' >> $GITHUB_ENV
